# pandas dataframe from a nested dictionary (elasticsearch result)

Tags: python, json, pandas, elasticsearch

I am having hard time translating results from elasticsearch aggregations to pandas. 
I am trying to write an abstract function which would take nested dictionary (arbitrary number of levels) and flatten them into a pandas dataframe

Here is how a typical result look like

-- edit : I added the parent key as well

```
x1 = {u'xColor': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 4,
u'key': u'red',
u'xMake': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 3,
   u'key': u'honda',
   u'xCity': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 2, u'key': u'ROME'},
     {u'doc_count': 1, u'key': u'Paris'}],
    u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
    u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}},
  {u'doc_count': 1,
   u'key': u'bmw',
   u'xCity': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 1, u'key': u'Paris'}],
    u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
    u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}}],
 u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
 u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}},
 {u'doc_count': 2,
u'key': u'blue',
u'xMake': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 1,
   u'key': u'ford',
   u'xCity': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 1, u'key': u'Paris'}],
    u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
    u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}},
  {u'doc_count': 1,
   u'key': u'toyota',
   u'xCity': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 1, u'key': u'Berlin'}],
    u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
    u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}}],
 u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
   u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}},
    {u'doc_count': 2,
u'key': u'green',
u'xMake': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 1,
   u'key': u'ford',
   u'xCity': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 1, u'key': u'Berlin'}],
    u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
    u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}},
    {u'doc_count': 1,
      u'key': u'toyota',
     u'xCity': {u'buckets': [{u'doc_count': 1, u'key': u'Berlin'}],
    u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
    u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}}],
 u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
 u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}}],
 u'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
 u'sum_other_doc_count': 0}}
```

what I would like to have is a dataframe with the doc_count of the lowest level

for the first record

```
 red-honda-rome-2 

 red-honda-paris-1

 red-bmw-paris-1
```

I came across json_normalize in pandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444797) but do not understand how to put the arguments and I and have seen different suggestions for flattening a nested dictionary but can't really understand how they work. 
Any help to get me started would be appreciated 
[Elasticsearch result to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165472/)

**UPDATE**

I tried to use [dpath](https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python) which is a great library, but I do not see how to abstract this (in form of a function which takes just the buckets names as arguments)  as dpath cannot handle the structure in which values are lists (and not other dictionaries)

```
import dpath 
import pandas as pd 

xListData = []
for q1 in dpath.util.get(x1, 'xColor/buckets'):
      xColor = q1['key']
for q2 in dpath.util.get(q1, 'xMake/buckets'):
    #print '--', q2['key']
    xMake = q2['key']
    for q3 in dpath.util.get(q2, 'xCity/buckets'):
        #xDict = []
        xCity = q3['key']
        doc_count = q3['doc_count']
        xDict = {'color': xColor, 'make': xMake, 'city': xCity, 'doc_count': doc_count}
        #print '------', q3['key'], q3['doc_count']
        xListData.append(xDict)

pd.DataFrame(xListData)
```

This gives:

```
city    color   doc_count   make
0   ROME    red     2   honda
1   Paris   red     1   honda
2   Paris   red     1   bmw
3   Paris   blue    1   ford
4   Berlin  blue    1   toyota
5   Berlin  green   1   ford
6   Berlin  green   1   toyota
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a recursive function:

```
import pandas as pd
def elasticToDataframe(elasticResult,aggStructure,record={},fulllist=[]):
    for agg in aggStructure:
        buckets = elasticResult[agg['key']]['buckets']
        for bucket in buckets:
            record = record.copy()
            record[agg['key']] = bucket['key']
            if 'aggs' in agg: 
                elasticToDataframe(bucket,agg['aggs'],record,fulllist)
            else: 
                for var in agg['variables']:
                    record[var['dfName']] = bucket[var['elasticName']]

                fulllist.append(record)

    df = pd.DataFrame(fulllist)
    return df
```

Then call the function with your data (x1) and a properly configured 'aggStructure' dict. The nested nature of the data must be reflected in this dict.

```
aggStructure=[{'key':'xColor','aggs':[{'key':'xMake','aggs':[{'key':'xCity','variables':[{'elasticName':'doc_count','dfName':'count'}]}]}]}]
elasticToDataframe(x1,aggStructure)
```

[image]

Cheers

Comment: many Thanks. fantastic ! defining the nested nature of the data is a good idea as it adds also the flexibility of the function.

Comment: Using mutable default argument is not a good idea.    
[See here more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 2):

There is a project could do this out of box: https://github.com/onesuper/pandasticsearch

It could also be done manually with a recursive generator and MultiIndex functionality:

https://github.com/onesuper/pandasticsearch/blob/master/pandasticsearch/query.py#L125